# Compute the frequency of objects over time in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have two matrices, "position" and "track", each of which are 402 by 1000. The 1000 represents 1000 objects, moving over 402 time steps. "Track" takes on integers 0-5, and position takes on floating-point numbers from 0-200. A track of 0 is considered off-track. I can plot all on-track objects using:

```
for indt = 1:ntimes
    plot(pos(indt,:), track(indt,:), 'o', 'MarkerSize', 18) ;
    title(['t = ' num2str(T(indt))])
    axis([0,200,0.5,5.5])
    pause(p)
end
```

Where ntimes=402, and the axis starting at 0.5 cuts off the off-track objects located at 0. The problem is, I'd like to see a histogram of off-track objects, the axes being position (so they need to be binned) vs. frequency. I am having such trouble with this! Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you draw an example figure? Not sure what exactly is meant with history and frequency.

Comment: History? I want a histogram, that updates over the 402 times steps, with the x-axis being position (0-200, but with, say 20 bins), and the y-axis being the frequency of objects in those positions. Does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you meant?

```
% Just some random data:
pos = rand(402,1000)*200;
track = randi(6,402,1000)-1;

% find all off tracks:
offTrack = track ==0;

% get the positions of the off tracks:
positionOfOffTracks = pos(offTrack);

% and plot this one
figure();
hist(positionOfOffTracks(:),20);
```

Comment: +1 - You beat me to it.  This is exactly what I would have done.

Comment: The problem with this, is I think you are making all of the "tracks" equal to zero. I want to find the objects are on track zero, and find the positions for those elements. Am I wrong?

Comment: @LuckyPenny - No.  What Steffen is doing is that in your `tracks` matrix, you search for every location in `tracks` that equals 0 (`offTrack = track == 0;`).  He then uses these locations to access the corresponding elements in your `positions` matrix to determine those tracks that were 0 (`positionOfOffTracks = pos(offTrack);`), then calculates a histogram on those extracted entries (`hist(positionOfOffTracks(:), 20);`).  The above will search for every possible object at every time instance having a track of 0, then bins these positions in a histogram.  I believe Steffen is correct here.

Comment: Ok, I see that now. How do I update this for each of the time steps? So the histogram should represent the position of the objects with track 0 (so in the first row of track), at the first time step, then update for all 402 rows of track.

Comment: last line replace with: `for i = 1:402;hist(positionOfOffTracks(i,:),20);end` each histogramm is shown individually

Comment: @LuckyPenny Make sure you add a `pause` at the end of each iteration so you can see what the histogram is for each time index.  Glad you got it to work!

Comment: @rayryeng Yeah I did! It looks good. It's a pretty cool stochastic model of neurofilament movement. Thanks, again!